# Simple user control for conditionally rendering nested HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, user-controls

What I would like to do, is be able to pass two attributes to a user control, a ListName and a Permission, like so:

```
<uc:check id="uc" List="Shared Documents" Permission="OpenItems" runat="server">
  <!-- have some HTML content here that is rendered if the permission is true -->
</uc:check>
```

Then in the actual *check* user control, have something similar to:

```
<%@ Control language="C#" ClassName="check" %>
<% 
  // determine permission magic placeholder
  if (DoesUserHavePermissions(perm))
  {
    // render nested HTML content
  }
  else
  {
    // abort rendering as to not show nested HTML content
  }
%>
```

I have read the page on [creating a templated control on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx), and while that would work - it really seems to be a bit overkill for what I am trying to do. Is there a control that already renders content based on a boolean expression or a simpler template example?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx

**Update:**

The following code can be used in the ascx to model a very simple version of this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="PermissionCheck" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.ComponentModel"  %>
<script runat="server">
    void Page_Init()
    {
        if (Allowed != null)
        {
            Panel container = new Panel();
            Allowed.InstantiateIn(container);
            PermissionBasedMessage.Controls.Add(container);
        }
    }

    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public ITemplate Allowed { get; set; }
</script>
<asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="PermissionBasedMessage" />
```

Note: I oversimplified the check in the Page_Init method for this sample code. Additional logic checks can be added as needed.

And reference it in the calling HTML page:

```
<%@ Register src="PermissionCheck.ascx" tagname="PermissionCheck" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<uc1:PermissionCheck ID="PermissionCheck1" runat="server">
  <Allowed>Allowed Access</Allowed>
</uc1:PermissionCheck>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are good for the generic form of your question, but for checking permissions SPSecurityTrimmedControl might do what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a custom control instead of a user control: derive from the asp.net panel, add your two properties, then only render the control if the user has the required permission. E.g. something like this:

The control (put this in App_Code for example):

```
namespace MyControls
{
    public class MyPanel : Panel
    {
        public string Permission { get; set; }
        public string List { get; set; }
        protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            if (UserHasPermission()) base.Render(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the control:

```
<%@ Page ... %>
<%@ Register Namespace="MyControls" TagPrefix="mc" %>
<html>
...
    <mc:MyPanel runat="server" List="Shared Documents" Permission="OpenItems">
        put content and/or other controls here
    </mc:MyPanel>
...
```

Comment: This is the way i'd do it. Very little code needed, and you won't lose any intellisense for inner controls.

Comment: This is perfect if I wasn't in SharePoint - App_Code is a bit painful when dealing with SharePoint

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you extend the LiteralControl, add properties for your settings, then render html to the .Value of the LieralControl?  Seems pretty simple and a lot less of a  headache than using Templated controls

Comment: I like this approach - I'll give it a shot and report back

Comment: This way you can control your output and not mess with having to set things visible = true/false.

Comment: Hmmm.... can't seem to embed this in an ascx. Would really like to avoid compiled assemblies and hence, code behind as well. 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'.

Comment: post your code -- it's not correct, and I can help you fix it.

Comment: This approach is dirty as you will have to set the HTML in the code-behind, and we all know that is an ASP.NET no-no

Comment: In WebForms?  A no-no?  Where else do you set it?  I am curious.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your content with a place holder control and set the control's visibility to true or false (controls that have .Visible = false won't render any html)

<asp:PlaceHolder id="phWrapper" runat="server">
...
</asp:PlaceHolder>

Then in your code-behind set phWrapper.Visible = DoesUserHavePermissions(perm);

Hope that helps!